# how to get image of a location from its latitude longitude in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-maps

Is it possible to get an image of a location from its Latitude and Longitude? i know google street view do provides a 360 degree view of that location but i need images/snaps of that location....Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to look at geocoding (rather reverse geooding).

An example from Mapquest API-

http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/

If you look at the GeoCoding api example, you can get the location from Lat and Long, and can also fetch the image of the area by specifying a bounding box.

Google has a [Reverse Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) as well.

OpenStreetMap has [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), which does reverse geocoding.

Edit - StreetViewApi

Gogole Street View API allows you to get the images of location, and takes in Lat/Long as parameter - details [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/#url_parameters)

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply! i am looking for an actual image of that location just like Google street View but the links you have have provided are about map's image rather than location's image. i want location's image rather than map's image

Comment: @DawoodKhanana - my bad, have added an edit which fetches StreetView images based on lat/long using Google StreetView api.